# Best way to fix the joists

Tags: structural, hole-repair

While doing the waste plumbing my overenthusiastic handyman bore holes bigger than 3 inches (in some cases 4 inches) into the 2x10 joists. He also notched the joist in one place. I am putting a 100 gallon tub on these 4 joists and it's making me super nervous. Besides this it will NOT pass the code.

I am looking to pull out the plumbing from these joists and structurally add the strength back to these joists. One idea is to sister the 2x10s with full length 2x10s (13 feet) and rest both the ends on the wall to properly support.

An inspector suggested that I add LVL 2x10 spanning 1 foot on either side of the hole/notch and rivet it with the weakened joist with Simpson Strong Ties SDS.

I am looking for advise on ways to fix the weakened joists.

Answer (score 1):

You better go with what the inspector suggests, that will be the simplest thing, since he has to approve it. Otherwise you will most likely need an engineer involved to come up with something and that will cost. Just getting advice from a DIY site will not satisfy the inspector

Answer (score 0):

I was not convinced that the inspector's solution will work. I ended up sistering the whole joist using LVL. Was a bit more expensive but the added strength makes me sleep better.